# rdlc report only shows first column

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

My report body is like this

```
<Body>
<ReportItems>
  <Textbox Name="Textbox3">
    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
    <Paragraphs>
      <Paragraph>
        <TextRuns>
          <TextRun>
            <Value>=Fields!VolID.Value</Value>
            <Style />
          </TextRun>
        </TextRuns>
        <Style />
      </Paragraph>
    </Paragraphs>
    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox3</rd:DefaultName>
    <Top>0.23833in</Top>
    <Left>0.2175in</Left>
    <Height>0.25in</Height>
    <Width>1in</Width>

  </Textbox>
</ReportItems>
<Height>2.68625in</Height>
<Style />
```

Server side code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet items = _rbl.GetConfirmedStaffAddress();
            reportviewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            LocalReport rep = rvConfirmedStaffForCamp.LocalReport;
            rep.ReportPath = "usercontrols/Reports/Report1.rdlc";
            DataSet ds = items;
            var rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]);
            rep.DataSources.Clear();
            rep.DataSources.Add(rds);

            rep.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

The dataset I bind to report viewer have 100 rows of data. but still I can see only first row in report. does any one have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either place your text box into "List" control or add "Table" control on your report and place your text box into detail row cell of the Table. You can make Table header invisible if you don't need it.